# jsp and angular doesn't see image

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I am using jsp to connect login page with spring secuity. In index.jsp I have included  ng-view. In another html file I would like to place a image. But application can't find path ... How should be this path ?

```
<img class="img-circle" src="/resources/registration/tmp_image/333395-352x500.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;">
```

Comment: Is there an image in the src path? If so does it appear if you go that path direct in the browser? I see you also have a class assigned to that image tag, what CSS is assigned to that class name?

Comment: try `<img class="img-circle" src="~/resources/registration/tmp_image/333395-352x500.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="180px" height="180px">`